# Get Connection String from datasource to customcode

Tags: oracle, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Is there a way to get the connection string from Reporting Service DataSource dynamically to the custom code in SSRS report?

Any help would be appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try ConnString from

SDS.DEF.nodes('/DataSourceDefinition')

Maybe [this](http://sqlmentalist.com/2013/09/25/bi-sql-174-sql-server-dba-scripts-list-connection-strings-of-all-ssrs-shared-data-sources/) can help.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Osy, But i want it to pull dynamically,I mean, im calling a table from custom code( ADO.net) and i need to grab the connection string for the database and i have to pass it to the custom code.